# Slow Boot-Up Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04, and have slow boot up time.

I have ran systemd-analyze blame and critical chain with the pictures down below

```
5min 7.004s fstrim.service 
1min 12.889s snapd.service 
52.687s networkd-dispatcher.service 
46.3995 lightdm.service
43.238s networking.service 
38.646s ModemManager.service 
35.840s dev-mmcblkOpl.device 
34.086s apt-daily-upgrade.service 
31.551s accounts-daemon.service 
28.993s apport.service 
28.070s pppd-dns.service 
28.031s lm-sensors.service 
27.801s teamviewerd.service 
27.146s NetworkManager.service 
23.254s motd-news.service 
20.735s NetworkManager-watt-online.service 
15.688s user@1000. service 
10.275s udisks2.service 
9.488s ssh.service 
6.3055 systemd-journal-flush.service
```

[image: systemd-analyze blame]

```
graphical.target @1min 59.675s 
multi-user.target @1min 59.675s 
teamviewerd.service @1min 31.873 + 27.801s
network-online.target @1min 31.442s 
NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 10.706 + 20.735s
NetwokrManager.service @37.790 + 27.146s
dbus.service @9.937s 
basic.target @9.779s
```

[image: systemd-analyze critical-chain]

Looking at it, it seems as though the main problem is the fstrim service?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1272165/edit) your question and rewrite the output of these commands as `code` instead. Then, they will show up in search engines, and may help future users who encounter the same problem.

To write something as code, select the text, and click on the `{}` in the page for editing.